# How to create a embedded form based on values of an entity attribute

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have an entity "Booking" linked to a "room" entity. The entity "room" has attributes like "Double Bed" and "Single bed".
Each room has recorded a number of double or single beds.
When I made a reservation, there are cases where I would be able to choose a bed

In my Booking form, I would like to have for each room a select for each bed (double bed one, double bed two, single bed one, ...)

How can I proceed?

Comment: As i am able to understand you are looking for select drop down based on your room entity which is having single or double bed options. Then you can use forms and go with entity type of drop down . For better understanding visit there: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: It's not exactly this. I have for each room a number of simple and double bed. I want display for each room, each bed and choose the bed I want book.

Comment: You can generate the content of the Select in your Controller, depending in your entity, and then pass and array containing the choices to your FormType

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the content of the Select in your Controller, depending in your entity:

```
$roomBeds = array();
if($entity->getSingleBeds > 0){
    $roomBeds['SINGLE_BED'] = "Single Bed";
}
if($entity->getDoubleBeds > 0){
    $roomBeds['DOUBLE_BED'] = "Double Bed";
}
```

With SINGLE_BED and DOUBLE_BED are the values for your attributs in your Reservation entity (as we don't have the names or the strcutures of your entities)

Then pass and array containing the choices to your FormType:

```
new RoomFormType($roomBeds)
```